# Always show controls on YouTube embedded iframe

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

Is it possible to always show the controls (disable autohide) on an embedded YouTube video?

I've tried adding `autohide=0` to the source url but the controls and progress bar still hide after a second or two. I'm confused because the [IFrame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autohide) states...

> 0 – Regardless of the player's dimensions, the video progress bar and player controls are visible throughout the video.

Is there something I'm missing or has the functionality been removed?

See: https://jsfiddle.net/hmpj3fn6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a little more digging...

> This parameter has been **deprecated** for HTML5 players, which display or hide the video progress bar and player controls automatically (autohide=1).

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autohide

Comment: Have you ever found a way to force controls to always stay and dont autohide?